# Reading 1-D Variables in WRF NetCDF files with GDAL python

Tags: python, gdal, netcdf, matplotlib-basemap

My question is simple.
With an wrfout file "out.nc" for example.
The file contain Geo2D, Geo3D and 1D variables.

Using *GDAL* package in Python 2.7, I can extract the Geo2D variables easily like this:

```
## T2 is 2-d variable means temperature 2 m above the ground
temp = gdal.Open('NETCDF:"'+"out.nc"+'":T2')
```

But when I want to use this code to extract 1d array, it failed.

```
## Time is 1-d array represent the timeseries throught the simulation period
time = gdal.Open('NETCDF:"'+"out.nc"+'":Time')
```

Nothing happened! Wish some one offer some advice to read any-dimension of WRF output variables easyily!

Comment: Have You tried using python-netcdf4 instead of gdal?

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the NetCDF reader in scipy.io:

```
import scipy.io.netcdf as nc

# Open a netcdf file object and assign the data values to a variable
time = nc.netcdf_file('out.nc', 'r').variables['Time'][:]
```

It has the benefit of scipy being a very popular and widely installed package, while working similar to opening files in some respects.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'll try!